# my react-app refreshes while navigating and waste the data in the redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

So my web app here is a small gift shop project and the probleme is when the user sign in everything goes very well and the user input are submitted to redux reducer after beeing validated with regex, and the homepage says hello {username} etc ...
the probleme is when the user navigate throught the app pages like clicking on a product to see the info about it and then click the browser back-button to go back to the homepage, the app refreshes and waste all the user input and i need to sign in again.
ive been working on this bug for 5 days HEEELP!!

This is **App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Main from './components/main/main';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import Items from './components/items/items';
import ProductInfo from './components/productInfo/productInfo';
import UserInterface from './components/userInterface/userInterface';
import Profile from './components/profile/profile';



function App() {

  
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router className="App">


        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={
            <div id='Homepage'>
              <Profile />
              <Main />
              <Items/>
            </div>
          }></Route>
          <Route exact path='/product-info/:id' element={<ProductInfo/>}></Route>
          <Route exact path='/user-form' element={<UserInterface/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
        
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
}




export default App;
```

This is **Profile.js** the component responsible to receive and display user data when needed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './profile.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { checkUser } from '../../actions/userActions';

class Profile extends Component {

    state = {
        user : {
            isLoggedIn : false,
            userName : '',
            email : '',
            password : ''
        }
    }


    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.checkUser()
        const currentUser = this.props.user.user;
        console.log(currentUser);
        this.setState({
            user : currentUser
        })
    }
    
    
    render() {

        const {user} = this.state;
        //const {checkUser} = this.props;
        

    return (
      <div>
        {user?.isLoggedIn ? <h2 id='welcome-user'>Welcome {user.userName}</h2> : 
            <a id="profile-area" href='/user-form'>
                <img src="user.png" alt="profile" id="profile-img" />
            </a>
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapUserStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        user : state?.myUser
    }
}

export default connect(mapUserStateToProps, {checkUser})(Profile);
```

This is **userInterface.js** the sign in form that take user input and submit it to redux reducer state.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import { getUser } from '../../actions/userActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import './userInterface.css';

function UserInterface(props) {

  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    isLoggedIn : false,
    userName : '',
    email : '',
    password : ''
  })

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  let alertMsg =  '';



  
  
  const getInputToState = (e,inputField) => {
    
    
    
    
    
    switch(inputField){
      
      
      case 'username' : {
        setUserInfo(userInfo.userName = e.target.value);
        const newUserInfo = userInfo; // create new state object
        setUserInfo(newUserInfo);
        console.log(userInfo);
        break
      }
      case 'email' : {
        setUserInfo(userInfo.email = e.target.value);
        const newUserInfo = userInfo; // create new state object
        setUserInfo(newUserInfo);
        console.log(userInfo);
        break
      }
      case 'password' : {
        setUserInfo(userInfo.password = e.target.value) ;
        const newUserInfo = userInfo; // create new state object
        setUserInfo(newUserInfo);
        console.log(userInfo);
        break
      }
      default:
        return null
  
      }
  }
  
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let namePattern = /[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}./ ;
    let emailPattern = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/ ;

    if(userInfo.userName?.match(namePattern) && userInfo.email?.match(emailPattern) && userInfo.password.length >= 8){
      setUserInfo(userInfo.isLoggedIn = true);
      props.getUser(userInfo);
      navigate("/");

      
    }else{
      document.querySelector('#alert-msg').innerText = 'username, email or password are invalid';
    }
    
  }
  
  
  
  return (
    <div id='user-div'>
        <form id='user-form'>

            <h2 id="form-title">Tell us who you are :)</h2>

            <ul id="form-inputs">
              <li className="form-input">
                <input type="text" className="user-input" placeholder='Enter a username' maxLength={16} onChange={(e) => getInputToState(e, "username")}/>          
              </li>
              <li className="form-input">
                <input type="text" className="user-input" placeholder='Enter your e-mail' onChange={(e) => getInputToState(e, "email")}/>
              </li>
              <li className="form-input">
                <input type="text" className="user-input" placeholder='Create a password' onChange={(e) => getInputToState(e, "password")}/>
              </li>
              <li className="form-input">
                <a><button className='action-form' id='submit-button' onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button></a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <h4 id='alert-msg' ></h4>


            

            <h3 id='login-sign'>Already have an account ? <a href="/" id='login-form'>Log In</a></h3>
            
        </form>
    </div>
  )


}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    myUser : state?.usersReducer
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getUser})(UserInterface) ;
```

And finally the **userReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    user : {
        isLoggedIn : false,
        userName : '',
        email : '',
        password : ''
    }
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'GET_USER':
            initialState.user = action.payload;
        case 'CHECK_USER':
            return{
                ...state
            }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

I guess these are all the components you need to help me.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using plain HTML `<a>` tag to navigate to other pages, which triggers the default browser navigation causing the refresh.

You have to use the `Link` component from the `react-router` library (see https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) in order to navigate to another page without refreshing.